# Use ng build watch & gulp watch on the same console

Tags: npm, gulp, angular-cli, watch

I would like to use `ng build --watch` & `gulp watch:ng` on the same console

Here's my task code

```
gulp.task('watch:ng', function () {
  gulp.watch('ng/dist/ng/*', gulp.series('copy-ng'));
});
```

I want to copy/merge the scripts to another location when angular rebuild the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution using `npm-run-all`

`npm install npm-run-all --save-dev`

```
"scripts": {
  "build:watch": "ng build --deleteOutputPath=false --watch",
  "gulp:watch": "gulp watch:ng",
  "rebuild": "run-p build:watch gulp:watch",
}
```

`npm run rebuild`